# What is the depth of the tree after two operations if the tree uses the "Move to Root" heuristics?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

I'm preparing for my finals in "Advance Algorithms". I'm trying to solve the following question:

> It is given that the current tree is a string of $n$ vertices, and a search operation is repeated twice, with each search looking for the key that resides at that moment in the deepest leaf of the tree. What is the depth of the tree after two operations if the tree uses the "Move to Root" heuristics.

By "tree is a string of $n$ vertices", I mean $n$ vertices $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ connected like so: $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}$ where $i\in[0,n-1]$ (not sure what's the English term for such graph). See example below to understand what I mean.

The answer to the question, should be $n-1$ but I don't see why. When I do a small example I get:

[image]

I guess I don't fully understand what's the right rotation algorithm but it feels like I did it right.

Could you please explain how did they got to $n-1$?

**EDIT**: I think I figured the issue. Another try (more detailed):

[image]

Is it correct? In this case I actually get $n-1$.

Comment: How is the depth of a tree measured here? Sometimes we count vertices, and sometimes edges.

Comment: @HendrikJan Hm, now that I think about it - I think that the depth in my courses is defined the number of edges from the root to the vertex. So I guess for both suggested solutions $n-1$. But which of them is correct?